# How to create button with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to use kivy for my project but I can't deal with it well..
I made a button, but I want that when I press him it will create another (new) button. Thanks a lot!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button

def createButton():
    b = Button(pos=(0, 90), size_hint=(.2, .2), on_press=lambda a:ad())
    return b

def ad():
    "crate new button here!"

class NoobApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return createButton()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NoobApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ad()` method add a line to create a Button and add it to the root of the app:

```
def ad():
    print("crate new button here!")
    App.get_running_app().root.add_widget(Button(text='hi'))
```

Note that this is adding a `Button` to a `Button`, (the `root` of the app is the original `Button`). Not a recommended approach. You should probably return some kind of `Layout` from your `build()` method instead.